# Is there solution for navigation for ViewController By programmatically In Objective-C (Cocoa) using Xcode 7.0

Tags: objective-c, iphone, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am trying to navigate one view controller to another view controller by using storyboard sheet segues, but it doesn't worked 
I took View1 and view 2 while navigating view1 to view2 it works well but after navigating view2 to view1 my GUI is freezing.
I think this problem arises because of thread synchronisation, So how can I manage this?

check my code in screenshot
[image]

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: i added link of screenshot please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUI related code should always be performed from the main queue, otherwise, it may not be performed immediately or not at all for that matter.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Do anything GUI/view related in the main queue
});
```

Comment: *** Assertion failure in -[NSWindowGraphicsContext reenableDisplayPosting], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1348.17/GraphicsContext.subproj/NSWindowGraphicsContext.m:132
2016-03-27 15:02:05.760 ANT_OBJ[2916:120691] An uncaught exception was raised
2016-03-27 15:02:05.761 ANT_OBJ[2916:120691] Invalid parameter not satisfying: _displayPostingDisableCount > 0
2016-03-27 15:02:05.761 ANT_OBJ[2916:120691] (
 0   CoreFoundation    ,this exception is caught after using this method